# Changing Yeoman File Structure and Related Grunt Changes

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm currently working on an AngularJS app which was generated with Yeoman. Yeoman and Grunt are both new to me, and I'm having a great deal of trouble trying to restructure this app into a more practical format.

Currently the app is structured as follows

```
app
--scripts
    --bower_components
        bower generated files 
    --services
        50 files
    --controllers  
        50 files
--views
    --more of the same
```

I've moved the bower_components out of the app folder, and in to the root. I also deleted the scripts and views folders, and structured everything in new folders grouped by functionality.

The problem is that I cant figure out how to change the grunt generated script tags in my html. If I change them manually, they are changed back to reference files which no longer exist. I have tried to play with the gruntfile, but I'm having no luck there either.

Any pointers would be appreciated, a search on this has gotten me nowhere to date.

Answer (score 0):

Yeoman is a scaffolding tool, it basically helps you to create a template that will help you better manage your project in the longer run.

I would suggest that you do not meddle with the structure given at this point and only change according to your need once you're more familiar with AngularJS

Comment: I've been using AngularJS for about a year, but I'm not familar with Grunt/Yeoman. I would like to use a scaffolding tool to make things easier, but with the current structure I find it unusable.

Comment: Default scaffolding tool won't let you make it feature wise. You can read more here:https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/109